# Node debugging, make `${file}` dynamic?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

With the right debug config file I can make VSCode run the currently focussed file through Mocha. However, I find it frustrating that if I am working on the actual code, rather than the spec file and I press `F5`, it tries to run the actual code as a spec file through Mocha.

So, my question is; given a file structure like this:

```
Folder
    File.js
    File.spec.js
```

And a debug config (`.vscode/launch.json`) like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Unit Tests: Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "-u", "tdd",
                "--timeout=999999",
                "--colors",
                "--opts", "${workspaceRoot}/mocha.opts",
                "${file}"  // I want to make this dynamic
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to get VSCode to debug the spec file whether the spec file (`File.spec.js`) or it's subject (`File.js`) are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new dynamic variable by writing a simple extension that just defines one command, e.g. a `smartFile` command.
Then you can refer to that command in your launch config as `${command:smartFile}`.

For the implementation of the command you can use everything available in VS Code extension API. So you can not only calculate a path based on your folder structure, but you can even pop-up UI. E.g. you could use QuickPick to select a test case from the list of all tests.

Comment: What would that look like, this?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_generated-code

Comment: Here is the extension: https://gitlab.com/atwright147/vscode-get-test-file